# One Request to index.php pausing other request until finish

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

I'm creating a single page application using php, where I have separate index.php 3 parts using URI like below,

```php
if(count($uri_segments) < 2) {
    // print the template, if no URI found.
}else {
    switch($route) {
        case 'start':
            // a CURL request via ajax from frontend, curl request taking 30s to complete even more.
            break;
        case 'status' :
            // other ajax call to display status
            break;
        default: break;
    }
}
```

Now I did async call to `/start` and `/status` normal like below

```js
async function() {
    await axios.get('./index.php/start').then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    });
}
axios.get('./index.php/status').then((res)=> {
    console.log(res);
});
```

But `/start` call blocking `/status` as you can see the below image.

> Img url: https://www.screencast.com/t/EXjyL8fYCl2q

I have to use only `index.php` page to build, any suggestions to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly you want to build? You want to call send request one after another or something else?

Comment: its like, need to call a curl and show the progress of same in html, soo /start will start the curl request and in the same time /status will fetch the status from backend(index.php/status).

Comment: Check the answer below.

Comment: Probably the usual problem with session file locking. Solution to that would be to call session_write_close in any long-running script as soon as possible.

Comment: You probably right @04FS, although I have close session write asap. Even I have tried my script without session use but nothing fruitful. Any else idea ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call endpoint one after another you can do like below.

```
function() {
    axios.get('./index.php/start').then((res) => {
        axios.get('./index.php/status').then((res)=> {
            console.log(res);
       });
    });
}
```

As you mentioned above you want to get status once start request is completed.

Comment: I think you did not get my point, Curl takes 30s even more to complete, I need to status simultaneously not after complete the request of /start.

Comment: So just remove `await` from your axios request from your original question.

Comment: Earlier I did't use async/await but the problem was same, then I thought this can be the solution but not work.

Comment: Can you please check your backend URL from postman(how much time its take) ?

Comment: I think the problem was not from javascript, its from php, because if I remove the curl call then its fine I guess, I have no idea why the request getting hold until other one finish.

Comment: It takes some time 13s some times 20s or more, Its depend on internet speed, not specific.